# Bootstrap ProgressBar increase column height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap grid and it has table and column in it and showing bootstrap progressbar, but it increase the column height, can any one guide why it is doing so, here is the my code how I am using it,

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="abc">
        <div id="xy" class="progress progress-striped active">
          <div id="xyz" class="progress-bar" style="width: 70%;">some text</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap CSS adds a 20px margin by default. You can override it by adding the following CSS:

```
.progress {margin-bottom:0}
```

http://jsbin.com/gajawu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Great Answer.. @Paul thanks Man, i was trying it from last two days and you did in minute or less.